# C++: Efficient way to check if elements in a vector are greater than elements in another having same indices?

Tags: c++, vector, comparison

I have a `vector < vector <int> >` like so:

```
v = {{1,2,3}, {4,2,1}, {3,1,1}....}}
```

All `v`'s elements like `v[0]`, `v[1]`, `v[2]`... have the same size. There may be duplicate elements.

What I am trying to do is to find and delete vectors (like `v[2]`) that are "majorized" by another vector (like `v[1]`), i.e. all elements of `v[1]` are greater than/equal to the respective elements(in order of indices) in `v[2]`.

A naive way of doing this would be to loop thorough `v` and compare each vector with another vector and further compare each element with another vector's element.

But I feel there must a better way to do this without getting `O(n^3)` in the number of elements of all the vectors in `v`.

If multiple vectors are equal, I need only one of them (i.e delete all except one). A random choice would be sufficient.

Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the [maxima of a point set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_of_a_point_set).  For two and three dimensions, this can be solved in O(n log n) time.  For more than three dimensions, this can be solved in O(n(log n)^(d − 3)  log log n) time.  For random points, a linear expected time algorithm is available.

Comment: Thanks! The algorithm on the wiki page helped.